# ReferenceError: Cannot access 'mockMethod1' before initialization

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have 3 source files File1.ts, File2.ts, File3.ts. While executing the Unit tests of File3 I am getting the following Error.

```
Test suite failed to run

    ReferenceError: Cannot access 'mockMethod1' before initialization

      20 |     __esModule: true,
      21 |     default: jest.fn(),
    > 22 |     method1: mockMethod1,
         |              ^
      23 |     method2: mockMethod2
      24 | }));
      25 |
```

Here are the contents of the 3 source files and unit tests for File3.

**File1.ts**

```
export default class File1 {
    public element;

    constructor(element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

     method1(inputs) {
         // Logic of Method1.
         return output;
     }

     method2(inputs) {
         // Logic of Method2.
         return output;
     }
}
```

**File2.ts**

```
import File1 from '../Folder1/File1'

export default class File2 {
    public file1Object;

    constructor(element) {
        this.file1Object = new File1(element);
    }

     method1(inputs) {
         // Logic of Method1.
         let out = this.file1Object.method1(inputs);
         // Logic of Method1.
         return output;
     }

     method2(inputs) {
         // Logic of Method2.
         let out = this.file1Object.method2(inputs);
         // Logic of Method2.
         return output;
     }
}
```

**File3.ts**

```
import File2 from '../Folder2/File2'
export default class File3 {
    public file2Object;

    constructor(element) {
        this.file2Object = new File2(element);
    }

     method1(inputs) {
         // Logic of Method1.
         let out = this.file2Object.method1(inputs);
         // Logic of Method1.
         return output;
     }

     method2(inputs) {
         // Logic of Method2.
         let out = this.file2Object.method1(inputs);
         // Logic of Method2.
         return output;
     }
}
```

**File3.test.ts**

```
import File3 from "./File3";
import File2 from "../Folder2/File2";

const mockMethod1 = jest.fn();
const mockMethod2 = jest.fn();

jest.mock('../Folder2/File2', () => ({
    __esModule: true,
    default: jest.fn(),
    method1: mockMethod1,
    method2: mockMethod2
}));

const file3Object = new File3(inputElement);
beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
});

test('Method-1 Unit Test', () => {
    mockMethod1.mockReturnValue(expectedOutput);
    let observedOutput = file3Object.method1(inputs);

    expect(observedOutput).toBe(expectedOutput);
})

test('Method-2 Unit Test', () => {
     mockMethod2.mockReturnValue(expectedOutput);
    let observedOutput = file3Object.method2(inputs);
     
     expect(observedOutput).toBe(expectedOutput);
})
```

I am not sure where I am making the mistake so I am unable to resolve this error. Any suggestions to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 13):

There are several things that are causing trouble. First, as mentioned in [jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#calling-jestmockdocsenjest-objectjestmockmodulename-factory-options-with-the-module-factory-parameter):

> A limitation with the factory parameter is that, since calls to jest.mock() are hoisted to the top of the file, it's not possible to first define a variable and then use it in the factory. An exception is made for variables that start with the word 'mock'. **It's up to you to guarantee that they will be initialized on time!**

What that means is you need to move around the lines of code to make them look like this:

```js
  // First the mock functions
  const mockMethod1 = jest.fn();
  const mockMethod2 = jest.fn();
  
  // Only then your imports & jest.mock calls
  import File3 from "./File3";
  import File2 from "../Folder2/File2";

  jest.mock('../Folder2/File2', () => ({
    // ...
  }));
```

The second issue is that you are mocking `File2` as if it was exporting `method1` and `method2`, you are not mocking `method1` and `method2` of the `File2` class! Take a look at [4 ways of mocking an ES6 class in jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#the-4-ways-to-create-an-es6-class-mock).

Comment: Oh my, you're a life saver.
Changing the mock function to be above the import was all I was missing, I've tried a ton of steps and that was the fix.

Comment: I was not actually "requiring" the item I was mocking but still could not get the hoisting error to go away until I saw this message. Renaming to start with the word "mock" and moving the creation to the top of the file before all other "require" functions helped.